# Finding best approach to SaaS with multiple databases, a shared resource, and EF

Tags: database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, multi-tenant, saas

First please excuse me for my grammar mistakes.

Ok, this is what I already know :-),
I want to use EF and MVC 4, UI with angularJs, I need a Database per user \ group of users,
my application growth may come to 5000+ users, they all have also a shared resource which is a single
database, when the user search for something the results will come both from the shared resource
and from the user own database.
Performance is extremely important.

In my research I found that EF can connect to different databases but i couldn't find any proper way of doing so without writing tons of code.
Scenarios :

1. New user registers, the system builds a new database for him.
2. New user logs in, the system returns data from his database and the shared database.
3. New user logs in, BUT, the system database got upgraded, users db should too.

Now I know that there is no easy method to achieve all of my goals,
but can you please direct me to what suits me best?

Again sorry for my English!
Thank you! :-)

Comment: _" I need a Database per user group of users"_ - why?

Comment: A group of users is like an office for example, and this office has its own agents, employees and so forth, and its own data, which some of it diffrent from other offices in terms of the data, lets say that one office look up table might look diffrent than another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, we have worked in several SaaS Applications that have been using a shared database [central repository] that will contain all the user [tenant] data and that there will be an application database [tenant based] for every user group.

This will work with ease in EF and there will be no performance overheads. You should not be using cross database queries and instead focus on the optimization of the EF code that you may have in the data access layer and then you can have separate services that will handle the task of merging the user data from the shared and separate databases.

May be you should analyze the application and then find the data that may be non-frequently updated and cache them and get them rendered using a distributed cache like Appfabric.

With respect to the synchronization of the User db and the centralized database, in the service tier, you can get this job done by wrapping these calls in a .Net Transaction scope and then the preserve the atomicity.

Please post your understanding and any further clarifications in my reply.

Comment: Thank you, the saas applications structure you have worked on is exacly what I to ecomplish in my application,

Comment: I'm looking for an implementation detail, how should I connect to a different db each time, services, what is going on beneath them, how should I create a different db, change its initializer and so on and so forth, I cant get my head around a suitable method or a pattern to achieve those goals, caching for some  non-frequent data, not a big problem, and I know that my repo will return the results from the shared and the tenant db's, but getting this the secured way including building it on the first time and taken care that it will upgrade correctly is something I cant figure out.

Comment: You will be having different services that take care of getting the data from the common database and the shared application database. In the service level the transaction scope ensures atomicity. May be I'll share a simple example for you shortly.